# C# - ExpandoObject definition

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, expandoobject

Looking at the definition of System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject i came across this:

```
public sealed class ExpandoObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, IDictionary<string, object>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, IEnumerable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ExpandoObject();
}
```

Why does the ExpandoObject class not implement the interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

The `ExpandoObject` has an [explicit implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the interfaces.
Explicit implentation allows it to only be accessible when cast as the interface itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using something like [.Net Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) you can see the implementation of each interface. The code is too long to post here but it is all in there. Simply do a search within reflector for the ExandoObject and you will see the members.

Answer (score 0):

I used [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) on  `System.Core 4.0.0.0`
and get

[image]

So implentations are present actually...

Comment: but why this is not visible through Visual Studio? Can I do the same with my types?